# GeoServer CQL Intersect Filter

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I am attempting to add a CQL filter to a WFS layer served from GeoServer. The result should display the pipelines which intersect landuse classes but for some reason I cannot get it to work. When using the preview in GeoServer the CQL filter works correctly.

I am storing the filter as a variable as such:

```
sewer_pipe_intersection_filter = ('Intersects' + '(' + 'geom' + ',' + 'collectGeometries' + '(' + 'queryCollection' + '(' + '"landuse_classifications"' + ',' + '"geom"' + ',' + '"INCLUDE"' + ')' + ')' + ')');
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I would advise you to check the CQL in the outgoing request in your browser's dev-tools and compare it with the succesfully tested string from the GeoServer preview. Maybe the strings are not the same.

Comment: please add the xml being sent to GeoServer to the question

Comment: Or, if not XML, the URL you're making the request to (in case of a GET request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the help, checking the returned string helped me fix the error.   Using this worked:

```
sewer_pipe_intersection_filter = 'INTERSECTS(geom,querySingle(' + "'Inyaninga_Live_Webmap:landuse_classifications'" + ',' + "'geom'" + ',' + "'land_use = '" + "'High Density Res''" + " '))";`
```

However the returned intersection has errors when compared to the result within the database, unsure what would be causing this.